# Quebra de texto dentro do Options do select html

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, html-select

Eu estou tentando quebrar o texto dentro do option ou simplesmente diminuir o tamanha do modal (dropdown) do select, mas não consigo. Alguem já conseguiu? como proceder nisto, estou preso com sistema nisto, pois ele precisa esta em responsivo e quero tudo organizado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poste seu código HTML/CSS relevante

Answer (score 1):

Para diminuir o *dropdown*, você pode usar a propriedade **width**, no elemento **select**.

```css
.select1 {
  width: 50px;
}

.select2 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Lorem ipsum dolor asit met</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="select2">
  <option value="volvo">Lorem ipsum dolor asit met</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Já quebrar o texto no **option**, eu não sei. No entanto, posso recomendar que você diminua a fonte do **select**.

```css
.select1 {
  font-size: 5px;
}
.select2 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select1">
  <option value="volvo">VolvoVolvoVolvoVolvoVolvoVolvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="select2">
  <option value="volvo">VolvoVolvoVolvoVolvoVolvoVolvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```